# not obvious geometry questions

Tags: geometry

I struggle in finding solution for difficult geometry questions. By difficult though, I do not mean they contain advanced concepts, but rather simple questions where the solution is not obvious. The greatest challenge for me is recognition, not knowledge or technique.

I would appreciate any recomendations to websites, books or any other resources that will help me to develop this skill. In particular, I only find geometry questions to be a problem so questions on that would be the most useful.

Thanks in advance

-in response to question-

[image: Diagram of problem]

Recently this question came up in a test: Given the three circles are identical, all with a radius of 24mm and their circumferences touch the edge of the rectangle, calculate the area of the rectangle. Although I now know how to solve this question I could not find a solution in the exam.

Comment: do you mean questions regarding proving geometric theorems, or something else?

Comment: like, clever usage of theorems @Sentinel135

Comment: Not necessarily proving a theorem, but if that requires fairly simple maths then yes. Any question that requires me to 'think outside the box' because I have a good theoretical knowledge but a sometimes just can't reach an answer.

Comment: yes, clever usage of theorems

Comment: We need to know your level of studies and/or your background in order to give you some "tailored" answers...

Comment: currently I am at GCSE level, I do not know calculus so i think I am at a similar level to pre-caculus in the USA

Comment: Could you give an example of one of the problems you're finding difficult in your post. This would make things much easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: Where have you been blocked in such a problem ? Had you found that the length of the rectangle is $4 \times 24=96$ ? If yes, it is a good starting point. Had you recognized an equilateral triangle, and identified it as a crucial point ? If yes, do you remember the formula for the height knowing the edge  ? (height = $\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times$ side) ?

Comment: I had a block when trying to identify the equilateral triangle. I don't know why but it just didn't come.

Comment: Here is "the worlds hardest easy geometry problem" http://thinkzone.wlonk.com/MathFun/Triangle.htm
and it is pretty hard to find the trick, but there is no mathematical knowledge required beyond high-school geometry.

Comment: {Plug} Try this course [Outside the box geometry](https://brilliant.org/explorations/essential-geometry/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I got the gist of what you're needing here. You are looking for information on the application of the geometric theorems you are learning. Most of these should be algebraic in nature.

The problem is, like most questions that are algebraic in nature, there are multiple ways to find the solution, and the key issue is never the answer but how you arrive at it.

Most of this can intuitively come by via practice. Even though it can be long and arduous, it does work.

Another way to deal with this is to question how the theorems work with each other. This would be like making your own problems and then finding a solution to them. It will be more work, but it will help you gain a better understanding.

As for resources, If you are using a book for studying this, then I definitely suggest using it. There are also websites like this that can help you with finding a solution. I would also suggest talking with a professor/teacher, as they will be able to help with the more difficult ones in a more one on one setting. They are experts at that thing, its what they do.

Finally if you are having test anxiety, the problem above kinda suggests that, then I definitely suggest talking to someone about it. It can be a extremely debilitating issue if not dealt with. Just keep in mind a test doesn't necessarily test a persons expertise in the subject matter, it only tests the capabilities of the person who made the test.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the centers of the circles: you will get an equilateral triangle with side length $48\,mm$, hence height $24\sqrt{3}\,mm$. Project the previous centers on the sides of the rectangle: it will be clear what the side lengths of the rectangle are, i.e. $96\,mm$ and $24(2+\sqrt{3})\,mm$. The area of the rectangle is so $\approx 86\,cm^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Just look horizontal and vertical lengths and dimensions. Vertically there is equilateral triangle height.

d= 48

$$ width= 2d,\, height = d+ \frac{\sqrt3 d}{2}, Area = d^2(\sqrt3 +2) $$

Plug in $d$ value.